# Meta description only displays in Google search for some search terms

Tags: xml-sitemap, meta-description, meta-keywords

I'm having issues with my keywords and description.when ever I search my site using an abbreviation with community for ex "tge community" or "tgecommunity" together it shows two different descriptions one being just my index page of my site and the other search being my index and meta description.

Below is in between my head tags.

```
    <title>My community title</title>
            <link rel="canonical" href="web url"/>
            <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"/>
            <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
            <meta property="og:title" content="Community title"/>
            <meta property="og:description" content="community title"/>
            <meta property="og:url" content="web url"/>
            <meta property="og:site_name" content="Abbreviation"/>
            <meta name="keywords" content="key words"/>
            <meta name="description" content="a sysnopsis of our community site"/>
            <meta name="identifier-url" content="web url"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8"/>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You can't control what search snippet will gonna display it. It's depend on user query. Google gonna display your meta description, only when it is helpful and related to user query.

Comment: Second @Goyllo here. Google chooses the meta description they want to how. Regarding sitemap, how did you upload it? And when you say it doesn't show up, what exactly is not showing up? Sitemap is just a list of pages for Google to discover. They will show these pages, not the sitemap. And adding a sitemap doesn't mean they will index all pages.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.   I've removed your second question.   If you want that answered, please ask in another post.

Comment: @IshanSharma My meta description doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Note always does Google shows what is in your meta tags, except they are similar to texts on your webpage. And also Google would show the user how that page relates to their search string, so in your case; Google finds out that the two string are not related and show the related description from each part of your website. And i don't think anything is wrong with the head tag, but check the body, that might be the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet that Google displays is no longer based on the meta description tag and hasn't been for a very long time. The snippet shown is based on the page content and the keywords from the users search. If Google assesses the description meta tag as the most suitable snippet based on the user query then it will be used otherwise a snippet from the page body will be used. There is not much you can do about this other than making sure your page content contains the keywords in a meaningful way that you are trying to target. The rest is done by Google and their proprietary algorithms.